# Angular pass checkbox value to custom pipe

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, checkbox

I'm looping through the values and displaying checkboxes which I'm showing, now in addition there is an search box filter on the top of list of checkboxes basically to filter out checkbox list.

HTML

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" class="lmn-input lmn-select-input-inner mt-input" placeholder="Search by key word" id="mngd-seg"/>


<div formArrayName="checkBoxValueList"
              *ngFor="let dataConceptList of scopeSetDetails.controls['checkBoxValueList'].controls | searchFilter : searchText; let i = index">
              <label class="lmn-selection-control">
                <span class="lmn-checkbox">
                  <input class="lmn-control-input" type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
                  <i class="lmn-control-icon lmnicon lmnicon-check"></i>
                </span>
                <span>Data Concept </span>
                <span style="padding-left: 150px">{{ checkBoxValueList[i].scopeSets }}</span>
              </label>
</div>
```

Therefore I've created an custom pipe '**searchFilter**' and using this pipe above in *ngFor

***PIPE***

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'searchFilter',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any, searchText: string): any {
    if (!items) return [];
    if (!searchText) return items;

    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
    return items.filter((it) => {
      return it.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
  }
}
```

In TS I'm initializing the checkboxes to false (with checkboxes, the Angular form control value is bound to the "checked" state (not the "value" attribute), so it should be either **true** or **false**) since it needs to be unchecked initially.

***TS***

```
      const formControls = this.checkBoxValueList.map(
        (control) => new FormControl(false)
      );
      const selectAllControl = new FormControl(false);

      this.scopeSetDetails = this.fb.group({
        search_text: this.fb.control(''),
        checkBoxValueList: new FormArray(formControls, this.minSelectedScopeSet(1)),
        selectAll: selectAllControl,
      });
```

Now issue is in filter pipe I'm getting `items` as an array of FormControl whose value property is 'false'. I need the checkbox text somehow and initially all checkboxes should be unchecked. how can I achieve this?

Comment: **never**, **never** [(ngModel)] and formControlName in the same tag

Comment: @Eliseo Yes I've removed formControlName

Comment: Why are you using pipe at all? its not recommended to filter in pipe, just modify  `scopeSetDetails`'s controls on searchTerm input change